# How to use pagination in angular with ng-repeat and ng-switch on condition

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to give pagination using angular Some problem with ng-switch on directive because with simple ng-repeat dir-paginate working fine. Pagination is not bind the data in it only shows few records in first page and another record are not shown while clicking on pagination control buttons.

```
<div ng-controller="QuestionsController">
<div>{{TagDescription}}</div>
<table style="width:80%">

    <tr dir-paginate="item in QuestionList|itemsPerPage:7 " ng-switch on="$index % 1">
        <td ng-switch-when="0">
            <div style="color:darkblue">

                <a ng-href="@Url.Content("~/Home/Answers/")?QuestionId={{QuestionList[$index].QuestionId}}"><b>{{QuestionList[$index].QuestionTitle}}</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="box"> {{QuestionList[$index].QuestionDescription}}</div>

            <br />
            <hr />
        </td>

        </tr>



</table>

<table align="left" style="margin-left:-62px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divpagination">
                <dir-pagination-controls 
                                         max-size="5"
                boundary-links="true"
                 direction-links="true">

                </dir-pagination-controls>

            </div>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```